# ProvisionError: Failed to provision Developer Portal bot registration pops up when trying to debug sample bot project locally

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm following the [guidelines](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v1.1.0/share-now#try-the-sample) to debug this **TeamsFx-Samples/share-now** at vscode, the provision & deploying process are all good, the bot has successfully been deployed on Azure.
However, the task 'set-up-bot' will fail and throw an error when i'm trying to debug the project locally:

```
[2022-12-11T02:55:29.879Z] [Info] - Finished 'Set up tab' Visual Studio Code task in 0.12 seconds.
[2022-12-11T02:55:29.917Z] [Info] - Running 'Set up bot' Visual Studio Code task.

(Totally 5 steps) Teams Toolkit is setting up bot for debugging.

(1/5) Registering the AAD app which is required to create the bot ...
(2/5) Registering the bot in Bot Framework Portal ...

Summary:

√ Skip registering AAD app but use the existing AAD app from args: c87d9e6d-5f17-4c76-abe3-5a1c1643e937

× ProvisionError: Failed to provision Developer Portal bot registration.
```

It looks like no documentation or issues about this error out there.

Would someone tell me what is this 'Registering the bot in Bot Framework Portal ' thing doing and how can I deal with this error?

1. What is this 'Registering the bot in Bot Framework Portal ' thing doing
2. how can I deal with this error.

Comment: Just letting you know that I am getting the same exact error today. So it may be a server-side issue??

Comment: 1. It registers your app as a bot with the bot framework in Azure. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/provision?pivots=visual-studio-code#create-resources

Answer (score 0):

**Updates:**
**The server-side API issue **was resolved** around two hours ago.**
I did a quick check, and the local debug experience of TTK was working good now.
Can you help **verify this** in your convenience and give some feedbacks here? Thanks.

after some investigations and verifications, It seems there's some live-site issues related to the underlying API of creating bot registration on bot framework portal. We're actively connecting with the corresponding team to handle this issue, please stay tunned, thanks.

Check this issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/7184 for latest updates, thanks.